# MongoDb pass regex to map function scope: MongoError: Failed to JS_NewX

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, mongodb-query

The regular expression:

`var OMIT_VERSION_NUMBER_REGEX = new RegExp("(\\d(,|\\.)?)+$", 'g');`

The map reduce call:

```
  let result = await collection.mapReduce(map, reduce,
    {
        out: { inline: 1 },
        scope:{
            omitVersionNumberRegex: OMIT_VERSION_NUMBER_REGEX,
        },
        query: query,
    }
);
```

Resulting in:

> MongoError: Failed to JS_NewX

Also tried this:

```
scope:{
     regex: {omitVersionNumberRegex: OMIT_VERSION_NUMBER_REGEX},
},
```

Which throws this error when utilising the regex in the map function:

> MongoError: Error: SyntaxError: invalid regular expression flag s @:6:1

The map function:

```
let map = function () {
    this.SOMESTRING.replace(omitVersionNumberRegex, '');
    // emit result...
}
```

Passing function and variable references works. How can a regular expression be passed to the scope of the map function, so that the regular expression only needs to be created once?

Comment: So why are you passing in a regex "constant" to the global scope variables anyway? Surely unless you need to take a value in the current content, then this can simply be part of the function code that wants to use it. The error might also be caused by your implementation in the map function. I would 1. Not pass in as scope and simply code the expression into the map function 2. If that were still throwing an error that I could not work out why, show that code to someone else. So do step 1 and if you need to then show us the map function code where you are using the regex.

Comment: @NeilLunn I only want to do a one line string manipulation, so I didn't wrap it in an extra function, but I could if its the only solution to solve this issue

Comment: So `this.SOMESTRING.replace(RegExp("(\\d(,|\\.)?)+$", 'g'), '')` then. Are you checking to see that `SOMESTRING` actually exists as a property before you do that? First point I was making is that passing a Regex via global scope that is a "constant" is pointless. Just code it. Second point I was making is make sure your implementing code is up to scratch. So change that, and there should be no problem. Unless there is something else you are not actually showing us that is.

Comment: Yep, I'm checking if the property exists but coding it in the function is compiling the regex everytime the map function is called which is for every document e.g. 10 000 times which results in bad performance

Comment: Sorry but you are asking a question here based on your extensive experience and intimate knowledge of MongoDB? Because it seems like you are the one "asking the question". So if you are "asking" then it's usually best to "do what you have been advised". If you just want to tell people how to do it, then asking a question is usually on the wrong side of that fence.\

Comment: @NeilLunn My question is if there is a way to pass a regular expression to the map function's scope. I know there are some workarounds, but my question is very specific. Idk why you get the impression that I want to teach people how to do it....

Comment: And asking if I do exception handling is not dealing with the issue I'm having